# Анимация android объекта ViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: android, анимация, kotlin

Хочу, чтобы после каждого нажатия на кнопку, мой элемент сдвигался. Однако после первого сдвига вправо больше он никуда не идет.

Писал так:

```
beatle.animate()
            .translationX(100f)
            .translationY(0f)
            .setDuration(1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему вы решили что он должен продолажать анимацию передвижения после первго нажатия? Когда вы нажимаете на кнопку то запускаете анимацию перемещения `view`-шки на заданые значения в методе `translationX(float value)`/`translationY(float value)`, при последующих нажатиях `view` уже стоит на этом месте куда ее пытаються снова поставить. Для примера можете инкрементировать значения при нажатии на кнопку и лишь потом передавать ее в `translationX(float value)`/`translationY(float value)`.